# Bootstrap tooltip in the same partial view renders when the partial view is initiated from one page, but fails when initiated from another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a common partial view (`_New.cshtml`) that is rendered from two different pages (`Loads-1` and `Loads-2`) in the application. Within the partial view there is a tooltip (on hover). 
The tooltip appears on hover as expected when the partial view is rendered from `Loads-1`. But, the tooltip does not appear when the same partial view is rendered from `Loads-2`.

I am new to .Net MVC and knockout.js So, am still trying to get my head around views, partial views, knockout data bindings and stuff.
 I tried plenty of variations, but the tooltip never seems to appear on `Loads-2` but always works on the first.

Are there any specific reasons why this is happening? Will be glad in case someone has some tips to debug this issue and get the expected result.

Following is the code I have implemented for the tooltip within the partial view:

```
<span class="tooltip-bca" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" data-bind="attr: { 'data-original-title': '@if (..) { tooltip content }' }">
    Hover Me
</span>
```

Comment: you probably need to re-initialize the tooltips since the data elements have changed?

Comment: @Nikki9696 Am not sure how I should be doing that. :/

Comment: Assuming bootstrap tooltips, just use your method of choice to jsscript invoke $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); - if that's not enough, please provide a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)